# Only filter out the alphanumeric text

Tags: php, filter

How can I only take the alphanumeric text and spaces from a given text.

I can do the regex and I have come up with -> [A-Za-z0-9 ]+ but I dont know any functions in php which will take the text and apply that rule and return me the match.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the preg_grep function. See the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

(source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

What about doing a little bit of research before asking questions?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find anything. Google hadn't been a very good friend.

Comment: @ Chris: What's the problem with asking for research? Commenting without helping seems to be the worse attitude.